# Using a switch statement in Wordpress

Tags: php, customization

I've got a piece of text in a div that I want to change on each page of my website. At the moment I'm not sure what function I should be using to do this. Here's what I have so far...

```
<?php
$page = is_page();
switch ($page){
case 'home':
$content = 'How much money....';
break;
case 'about':
$content = 'We design....';
break;
case 'services':
$content = 'At the....';
break;
case 'blog':
$content = 'Find out whats....';
break;
case 'portfolio':
$content = 'Unique, Beautiful....';
break;
case 'contact':
$content = 'Get in touch to....';
break;
case 'privacy-policy':
$content = 'How much money....';
break;
case 'terms-and-conditions':
$content = 'How much....';
break;      
}

echo '<div class="strapline strap">'.$content.'</div>';
?>
```

This code only seems to be picking up the first case for every page. Anyone know how I can get it to run through the switch completely? 
Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: ['is_page()'](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) only returns a boolean true/false so will never work in the above context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanted to use your switch statement, you could use:

```
switch ($post->post_name){
    case 'home':
        $content = 'How much money....';
        break;
    case 'about':
        $content = 'We design....';
        break;
    case 'services':
        $content = 'At the....';
        break;
    case 'blog':
        $content = 'Find out whats....';
        break;
    case 'portfolio':
        $content = 'Unique, Beautiful....';
        break;
    case 'contact':
        $content = 'Get in touch to....';
        break;
    case 'privacy-policy':
        $content = 'How much money....';
        break;
    case 'terms-and-conditions':
        $content = 'How much....';
        break;      
}

echo '<div class="strapline strap">'.$content.'</div>';
```

First. I would follow [@rrikesh approach](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/94271/11966) of using if/else and use is_page() correctly.

But this code is really inefficient. If you can do an "is_page()" test, then you are on the page, and have access to it's content. Personally, I would add a custom field to the pages to hold $content. Then on the pages, you can simply call the custom field

```
$content = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'content', true);
echo '<div class="strapline strap">'.$content.'</div>';
```

You can use a free plugin like Advanced Custom Fields to quickly add a custom meta field to your pages and your content is easier to organize and edit later.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use `if` and `else` instead of a switch.

`is_page` will just check if you are on a page and will return `true` or `false`. It will not return your page name.

What you need to do:

```
if ( is_page('Home') ){
  #do home stuff
}
elseif( is_page ('about') ){
  #do other stuff
}
elseif( is_page('services'){
  #do services stuff
}
```

Look at [`is_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) for parameters you can pass.

Answer (score 0):

`is_page()` is a boolean function, it only returns true or false.

You might find using `$page = get_the_title()` a reasonable alternative.

Comment: You would want to get the post_name not the title. or just test on title instead...